# My app works on Chrome and not on Firefox. I don't understand the error. "Component returned failure code: 0x80004001 "

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, svelte

I have a Svelte app that works on Chrome. When using Firefox it throws an error. I have no idea how to fix this. In Chrome the app works fine with no errors. In Firefox the screen goes blank. I have posted a screen shot of the errors below. I usually try to troubleshoot before I post to SO but with this error I seriously have no idea how to fix it without ripping my app to shreds.

```
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) [nsIAppStartup.secondsSinceLastOSRestart]"  nsresult: "0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)"  location: "JS frame :: resource:///modules/BrowserGlue.jsm :: _collectStartupConditionsTelemetry :: line 1593"  data: no]
```

[image]

Comment: 1. Are you testing your app in a private/incognito window, i.e. without any extensions/add-ons that might interfere? 2. Are you using any language (i.e. Javascript) features that are not supported in Firefox?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the code in BrowserGlue.jsm :: _collectStartupConditionsTelemetry :: line 1593